# Collecting Data in Repository and ViewModel with Coroutines and Flow

Tags: kotlin, android-room, viewmodel, kotlin-coroutines

**Hello everyone,**
As part of my work on a caching app, I encountered a situation where I'm returning a Flow<List> from the DAO and have corresponding functions in the repository interface and implementation that return Flow<List>. To retrieve the data, I find myself collecting the data from the DAO function in both the repository and the ViewModel.

I would like to discuss the best practices when it comes to collecting data in both the repository and the ViewModel. Is it a good idea to collect the data in both places? Are there any potential drawbacks or issues with this approach?

Dao

```
@Dao
interface MovieDao {

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    suspend fun saveMovies(moviesEntity: MoviesEntity)
    
    @Query("SELECT * FROM movies")
    fun getMovies(): Flow<List<MoviesEntity>>?

    @Query("DELETE FROM movies")
    suspend fun clearMoviesListing()


}
```

MovieRepository Interface

```
interface MovieRepository {

    fun getMoviesResult(
        category: String,
        fetchFromRemote: Boolean,
    ): Flow<Resource<List<Movies>>>
}
```

MovieRepositoryImpl

```
  override fun getMoviesResult(
        category: String,
        fetchFromRemote: Boolean
    ): Flow<Resource<List<Movies>>> {

        return flow {

            while (true) {
                emit(Resource.Loading(true))

                movieDao.getMovies()?.collect { listMovieEntity ->

                    if (listMovieEntity.isNotEmpty() && !fetchFromRemote) {
                        emit(Resource.Loading(false))

                        emit(
                            Resource.Success(data = listMovieEntity.map {
                                it.toMovies()
                            })
                        )
                    } else {

                        val remoteListing = try {
                            movieApi.getMovies(category = category)
                        } catch (e: IOException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            emit(Resource.Error("Couldn't Reach Server, Check Your Internet Connection, Try Refresh"))
                            null
                        } catch (e: HttpException) {
                            e.printStackTrace()
                            emit(Resource.Error("Couldn't Reach Server, Check Your Internet Connection."))
                            null
                        }

                        if (remoteListing !== null) {

                            emit(Resource.Loading(false))

                            remoteListing.let { movie ->

                                movieDao.clearMoviesListing()

                                movieDao.saveMovies(movie.toMoviesEntity())

                                movieDao.getMovies()!!.collect() { s ->
                                    emit(
                                        Resource.Success(data = s.map {
                                            it.toMovies()
                                        })
                                    )
                                }


                            }
                        }
                        emit(Resource.Error(message = ""))
                        emit(Resource.Loading(false))
                    }


                }
            }


        }

    }
```

View Model
private fun getMovieResult(category: String, fetchFromRemote: Boolean) {

```
    viewModelScope.launch {

        movieRepository.getMoviesResult(category, fetchFromRemote)

            .collect { results ->

                when (results) {

                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        results.data?.let { result ->
                            state = state.copy(movies = result)
                        }
                    }

                    is Resource.Error ->
                        state = state.copy(
                            error = results.message ?: "An unexpected error occurred"
                        )

                    is Resource.Loading -> state = state.copy(isLoading = results.isLoading)

                }
            }
    }
}
```

In my case, the DAO function returns a Flow<List>, which is a type that represents a stream of data that can change over time. To access the data from the DAO, I need to collect it using the collect function to receive updates whenever the data changes.

Since the repository interface also has a function that returns a Flow<List>, which represents the desired data type for the ViewModel, I need to transform the collected MoviesEntity objects into Movie objects. For this transformation, I utilize the repository implementation (e.g., MovieRepositoryImp) to map the entities to the desired model.

Therefore, to correctly utilize the Flow and ensure the data flow through the layers of the app, I find it necessary to collect the data in both the repository and the ViewModel.